Issue connecting to AWS RDS database from remote computer
I have an AWS RDS SQL Server database configured with a public access option. I can successfully connect to the database from my own computer, but when attempting to connect from another external computer, I encounter the following error:

TITLE: Connect to Server
Cannot connect to
myserver.rds.amazonaws.com.
------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
For help, click:
https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-53-database-engine-error

Cannot find the network path

Steps I have taken:
The AWS RDS database has a public access option, and I have configured the appropriate security groups to allow inbound connections on port 1433 from any IP address range (0.0.0.0/0).
I am using the correct database instance name (myserver.rds.amazonaws.com) and port (1433) for connecting.
I can successfully connect to the database from my own computer using SQL Server Management Studio.
I have checked for any local firewall settings that might be blocking connections to external servers like AWS RDS.
Despite these efforts, I continue to receive the error when attempting to connect from an external computer. Can anyone suggest what might be causing this issue or any further steps I can take to resolve it?
Thank you in advance!

Never EVER publish your servers address in a public forum. I've edited it to remove it.

Second: never ever do this "from any IP address range (0.0.0.0/0)."

I strongly recommend changing that firewall rule IMMEDIATELY. You have exposed your server url and confirmed it's open to access from everyone; people can and will be attempting to brute force their way into your server. You should consider that URL already out "in the wild", and multiple scrapers will have already consumed it.

"Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53" often indicates a DNS resolution issue, as in the host name "myserver.rds.amazonaws.com" cannot be resolved to an IP address that the computer can use to connect to. Try opening a PowerShell window on the problem computer and using Resolve-DnsName -Name myserver.rds.amazonaws.com to see if that's the case.

the results from the Resolve-DnsName command. It looks like DNS resolution is working correctly
